# no module named 'speech_recognition'

Tags: python-3, speech-recognition

I installed speech recognition

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

ran this

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

    print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

and got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    import speech_recognition as sr
ImportError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

Comment: did you figure this out ? if yes can you share with us please?

Comment: Yes, my problem was I didn't specify python 3, `pip3 install SpeechRecognition` worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your tag says python3. If you are running your code in python3 you need to install speechrecognition with pip3.

Answer (score 1):

As [T. M.'s answers](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/96437/19949) points out you need to make sure that the modules are installed for the Python version you are using.

If you're running several version of Python and pip you might want to check that you are using the corresponding pip version. It might look like this:

```
# python --version
Python 3.7.1
# pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

If `pip --version` returns something not reading "(python 3.x)" you should use `pip3` to install modules for Python3. However, since End of Life for Python 2.7 is coming any sane distribution would want `pip` to be `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would check to see if the file it's trying to access is in the folder that it's suppose to be in.  Next if that all checks out look at the version of Python you are using and the version it's suppose to work on.